# Calculating the Average Minimum Length of Random Numbers From 0 - 1 that Adds up to Greater Than 1

Tags: python, python-3.x, time-limit-exceeded, memory-optimization

My Computer Science teacher gave us a task to calculate the average after one billion trials.

His exact assignment was this:

> Consider generating a sequence of random numbers on the interval [0, 1) perhaps using Math.random() in a loop and adding them together.  How many numbers would you expect to generate in such a sequence before the sum exceeds 1.0 ? (i.e. probability)
>
> Write a program that simulates these trials a billion times and calculates the average length of the sequences.
>   This is a neat exercise in nested loops.
>
> Examples:
>
> - 0.449   0.814
>
>   - length of sequence: 2
> - 0.167 0.138 0.028 0.934
>
>   - length of sequence: 4
> - 0.640 0.258 0.417
>
>   - length of sequence: 3
> - 0.911 0.212
>
>   - length of sequence: 2
>
> Average of the four lengths is 11/4 ≈ 2.75
>
> What is the average of one billion random sequences?

My code was this:

```
import random

def genSequence():
  storenums = 0
  numTrials = 1000000000
  for x in range(0,numTrials):
    numberOfAttempts = 0
    getToOne = 0 
    while (getToOne < 1): #keeps on generating random numbers and adding it to getToOne until it reaches 1 or is over 1
      getToOne += random.random()
      numberOfAttempts += 1
    storenums = storenums + numberOfAttempts
    #print (x)
    #print(storenums)
  calculateAverage(storenums,numTrials)

def calculateAverage(num,den):
  average = num/den
  print(average)

genSequence()
```

*Note: I am using repl.it to run my code so there is no main.

The problem with my code is that it can't reach 1 billion trials and stops working at around 227,035. I'm pretty sure this is a memory issue but I don't know how to fix this. What can I do so that it actually completes the billion trials and preferably not in an egregiously long amount of time.

EDIT: My teacher the result should be e, but that isn't the point as I just need to write the code. Getting e just means I did it right.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If I rewrite `genSequence` so that it takes `numTrials` as an argument, then I get the following timing in CPython:

```
Python 3.6.4 (default, Dec 21 2017, 20:33:21) 
>>> from timeit import timeit
>>> timeit(lambda:genSequence(10**8), number=1)
2.71825759
62.77562193598715
```

Based on this, it would take about 10 minutes to compute `genSequence(10**9)`. Possibly you just didn't wait long enough.

This kind of loop-heavy numerical code generally runs much faster if you use PyPy, which has a "just-in-time" compiler. I get more than ten times speedup with PyPy:

```
[PyPy 5.10.0 with GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 9.0] on darwin
>>>> from timeit import timeit
>>>> timeit(lambda:genSequence(10**8), number=1)
2.71816679
5.389536142349243
```

On PyPy you should be able to carry out \$10^9\$ trials in under a minute (on my computer it takes 51 seconds).

Some review points:

1. The number `1000000000` is hard to read — it could easily be confused with `100000000` or `10000000000`. I would write `10**9` to make it clear.
2. There's no need for the variable `numberOfAttempts`; you could just add one to `storenums` on each loop.
3. The name `storenums` is a bit vague. This is the total length of the random sequences generated so far, so a name like `total_length` would be clearer.
4. Similarly, the name `genSequence` is vague. This calculates the mean length of a random sequence, so a name like `mean_sequence_length` would be clearer.
5. The meaning of the constant 1 is not altogether clear. I would give it a name like `target_sum`.
6. When a loop variable like `x` is not used, it's conventional to name it `_`.
7. `range(0,numTrials)` can be written `range(numTrials)`.

Revised code:

```
import random

def mean_sequence_length(trials, target_sum=1.0):
    """Return mean length of random sequences adding up to at least
    target_sum (carrying out the given number of trials).

    """
    total_length = 0
    for _ in range(trials):
        current_sum = 0.0
        while current_sum < target_sum:
            current_sum += random.random()
            total_length += 1
    return total_length / trials
```

Comment: Additionaly, instead of writing `10**9`, one could write `1_000_000_000`.

Comment: @Gareth Rees I've run it on PyPy and it certainly much faster with your edits but it is not running in under a minute like you said it should. Would that be a computer issue or more like some mistake on my part?

Comment: @PGODULTIMATE: Maybe my computer is faster than yours. Measure the performance on some smaller values of `trials` and extrapolate to work out how long it is going to take.

Comment: I measured preformance an it says 63.16667 minutes.

Comment: Actually I realized that I didn't comment out my print statement (I used it to check progress). Now the preformance time is about 1.252 minutes for 1 billion trials. Thank you very much!